# Move all uploaded files to E:/ drive using laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can be move all uploaded files to the E: drive using Laravel? This is my code:

```
$test = "E:";
$path = "checklist/uploads";
$destinationPath = $test . "/$path/";    
if (!file_exists($destinationPath)) {
    mkdir($destinationPath);
}
```

Comment: $file->move($destinationPath, $destinationPath . $fileName, 0777,true);
 chmod($destinationPath . $fileName, 0777);

Comment: When adding info to your Question, please edit instead of commenting! See also [ask] and read about [mcve].